# Identify the Celebrity: how does using a queue save logn questions?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, queue, time-complexity

I am reading [this paper](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/spring13/cos423/problem0-1.pdf) and at the end in the "A Slight Improvement" section, the author said we can save on an additional $log_{2}n$ questions by using a queue instead of an array.

I don't understand how this works. I tried it out on paper with 8 people and the same number of questions was asked in the elimination process whether an array or a queue was used.

Here is the code for the array method:

```
procedure Eliminate(V, E)
    L ← MakeList
    for v ∈ V do
        add(L, v)
    while L contains at least two elements do
        u ← Remove(L)
        v ← Remove(L)
        if HasEdge(u, v) then
            Insert(L, v)
        else
            Insert(L, u)
    s ← Remove(L)
    return s
```

and here is the queue pseudocode

```
procedure Eliminate(queue)
    while queue.size() >= 1 do
        u ← queue.pop_front()
        v ← queue.pop_front()
        if HasEdge(u, v) then
            queue.push_back(v)
        else
            queue.push_back(u)
    s ← queue.pop_front()
    return s
```

Here is the verify function

```
def verify(guests, c):
    for g in guests:
        if HasEdge(c, g) or !HasEdge(g, c):
            return false
```

Could you please explain how they two methods differ in terms of number of comparisions performed?

Comment: The elimination-process doesn't differ in the number of comparisons. The interesting point is that the log2(n) comparisons which were made against the sink don't need to be repeated during checking whether the candidate found by the elimination is actually a sink.

Comment: @Paul but `how`???

Comment: Well, that's hard to tell, without seeing any code for the steps after the elimination-process. In this example I couldn't tell you at all, since the two pseudocode snippets basically don't differ at all from a logical POV. Well, apart from the mistake with `while queue.size() >= 1 do ...`.

Comment: I added the verify function to the code

Comment: My best guess would be to create a list of vertices for each potential sink and add the points that were eliminated to the list of the sink. Now the task becomes to create the counterpart - the list of vertices without those that were eliminated using the sink - and you've got the list you need for verification.

Comment: My best guess would be to create a list of vertices for each potential sink and add the points that were eliminated to the list of the sink. Now the task becomes to create the counterpart - the list of vertices without those that were eliminated using the sink - and you've got the list you need for verification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The methods you wrote are not different. You missed the point.

A potential sink v have been called to `HasEdge` at least `log(n)` times (that can be easily prof) in the `Eliminate` method.

The problem is all about minimizing the `HasEdge` calls. a Dictionary for each potential sink that remember the calls will save `log(n)` calls to `HasEdge` in the `Verify` method.

Code can be something like this:

```
procedure Eliminate(V, E)
    L ? MakeList
    for v ? V do
        add(L, Tuple(v, new Dictionary<Edge,bool>()))
    while L contains at least two elements do
        u ? Remove(L)
        v ? Remove(L)
        if HasEdge(u[0], v[0]) then
            v[1].add(Edge(u[0], v[0]),true)
            Insert(L, v)
        else
            u[1].add(Edge(u[0], v[0]),false)
            Insert(L, u)
    s ? Remove(L)
    return s

procedure Verify(V, s)
    for v ? V \ {s[0]} do
        if (s[1].Contains(Edge(s[0],v)) then
            if s[0][Edge(s[0],v)]
                return false;
        else
            if HasEdge(s[0], v)
                return false

        if (s[1].Contains(Edge(v,s[0])) then
            if !s[0][Edge(v,s[0])]
                return false;
        else
            if !HasEdge(v,s[0])
                return false
    return true
```

Comment: So why does the author make it sound like using a queue makes a difference if it does not?

Comment: Saving the calls to `HasEdge` makes a difference. You can do that with a list a queue or whatever as long as you don't repeat `HasEdge` calls you already made.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how I can modify the verify function in the paper to as logn less questions?

Comment: @user6005857 I added a full example with a dictionary for you.